# Qt5 project is not stable with QtSerialPort

Tags: build, cmake, qt5

Two identical Qt5 projects with different names. One handles the ReadyRead QtSerialPort the other is not. What could be the reason?

The build folder itself was deleted does not help (with the transfer of a troubled project to a different folder is working fine).

Windows7x86 mingw32 Qt5.12.5

In [github.com](https://github.com/ggshaman888/my_example/tree/936ff8f49116ef535827c711f8bdda0d7e8ccbc2/QSerialTest)

Comment: "What could be the reason?" - It could be *undefined behavior* caused by the incorrect code. It is difficult to say more without viewing the code.

Comment: Please, add the code to the **question post** itself (as text). Link is insufficient. Among other things, having code in the question post is a **requirement** of the Stack Overflow. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm CMakeLists.txt.user*
```

And deleted all build folders, including those not related to the project. QtCreator sometimes mixes the build folder paths with other projects.